# Help with obtaining the derivation of the resonance frequency of a bubble

Tags: homework-and-exercises, resonance, bubbles, liquid-state

I have a question with regards to the derivation of the resonance frequency of a bubble described using the bubble dynamics equation in the paper I'm currently reading (Eqn 1):
$$\frac{3}{2}R_t^2+RR_{tt}=\frac{P_i-P_e}{\rho_l}$$

where $P_i$ and $P_e$ is the internal and external pressure for the bubble. In order to find the resonance frequency of the bubble, the author defined the following variables as (Eqn 2-4):
$$R=R_0(1+\tilde{R}e^{i\omega_0 t})$$
$$P_i=P_0(1+\tilde{P_i}e^{i\omega_0 t})$$
$$P_e=P_0(1+\tilde{P_e}e^{i\omega_0 t})$$
According the the author, the 3 equations are then substituted into the bubble dynamics equation and subsequently linearised to obtain (Eqn 5)
$$-\omega_0^2R_0^2\tilde{R}=\frac{P_0}{\rho_l}(\tilde{P}-\tilde{P_e})$$
I tried to attempt the derivation, first by finding $R_t$ and $R_{tt}$ from $R=R_0(1+\tilde{R}e^{i\omega_0 t})$ as (Eqn 6 and 7):
$$R_t=R_o\tilde{R}(i\omega_0)e^{i\omega_0 t}$$
$$R_{tt}=R_o\tilde{R}(i\omega_0)^2e^{i\omega_0 t}$$
Next, I substituted $R$, $R_t$, $R_{tt}$, $P_i$ and $P_e$ in the bubble dynamics equation, after some factorisation, ended up with (Eqn 8)
$$-5/2R_0^2\tilde{R}^2\omega_0^2e^{2i\omega_0 t}-R_0^2\tilde{R}\omega_0^2e^{i\omega_0 t}=\frac{P_0}{\rho_l}e^{i\omega_0 t}(\tilde{P_i}-\tilde{P_e})$$
After this step I am currently lost on how to eliminate the first term on the left hand side. After some research I came across a [link](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/25017/4/chap4.htm) describing a similar problem which states that the $\tilde{R}^2$ term can be ignored, which would allow me to obtain Eqn 5.

My first question is would it be correct to just ignore the first term or is there a proper way to eliminate the first term on the LHS (maybe a consequence of  the linearisation step which the author mentioned?)

Another problem I have is related to the adiabatic condition, defined as for the internal pressure of the bubble which is defined as (Eqn 9)
$$P_iR^{3\gamma}=constant$$
Which according to the paper after substitution and linearisation can be written as (Eqn 10):
$$\tilde{P_i}=-3\gamma\tilde{R}$$
After doing my own substitution I am currently stuck at how to deal with the term with the exponent $3\gamma$ which I tried to expand but it turned seemed too complicated to be correct.

My second question would be how to perform this step, as I am unsure of how to deal with the RHS of Eqn 9 (what does the equation being a constant mean?) and the exponent $3\gamma$.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the correct direction on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In this derivation, we are considering only the linear approximation of the nonlinear equation 1. Thus, in order to be accurate, all terms must be of the $1$st order. As the $1$st term has a term $\tilde{R}^2$, it must be neglected.
2. Let us differentiate Equation 9 by $t$. We get 
   $$\frac{dP_i}{dt}R^{3\gamma}+3\gamma P_iR_i^{3\gamma-1}\frac{dR}{dt} = 0$$
   Substituting Eq. $2-4$, we get 
   $$P_0\tilde P_i(i\omega_0)e^{i\omega_0 t}R_0^{3\gamma}(1+\tilde Re^{i\omega_0 t})^{3\gamma}
   + 3\gamma P_0(1+\tilde P_ie^{i\omega_0 t})R_0^{3\gamma-1}(1+\tilde Re^{i\omega_0 t})^{3\gamma-1}R_o\tilde{R}(i\omega_0)e^{i\omega_0 t}$$
   Simplifying, we get -
   $$\tilde P_i(1+\tilde Re^{i\omega_0 t})+3\gamma\tilde{R}(1+\tilde P_ie^{i\omega_0 t}) = 0$$
   Linearizing, this becomes $\tilde{P_i}=-3\gamma\tilde{R}$.